# Converting linear grammar to normal form

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

I have a grammar that has the following productions:

$S\to aSbb$, $S\to aSa$ and $S\to c$

I am supposed to convert this grammar to normal form where the productions have to be as follows:

$A\to aB$ where $AB\in V$ and $a\in \Sigma$

$A\to Ba$ where $AB\in V$ and $a\in \Sigma$

$A\to \epsilon$

I have gotten some way, but I struggle with the fact that it seems that the number of $b$'s has to be even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Eliminate $S$ from RHS**: Replace the start symbol by $S_{0}$; the grammar becomes:

\begin{align}
& S_{0} \to S \\
& S \to aSbb \mid aSa \mid c
\end{align}

**Eliminate RHS with more than one non terminal:** Begin by replacing $S \to aSbb$ with:

\begin{align}
&S \to aA \\
&A \to Bb \\
&B \to Sb \\
\end{align}

The grammar thus becomes:

\begin{align}
&S_{0} \to S \\
&S \to aA \mid aSa \mid c \\
&A \to Bb \\
&B \to Sb \\
\end{align}

And then, replace $aSa$ by:

\begin{align}
&S \to aC\\
&C \to Sa\\
\end{align}

Leaving us with grammar:

\begin{align}
&S_{0} \to S\\
&S \to aA \mid aC \mid c\\
&A \to Bb\\
&B \to Sb\\
&C \to Sa\\
\end{align}

**Eliminate unit productions:** The final grammar comes by replacing $S \to c$:

\begin{align}
&S_{0} \to S\\
&S \to aA \mid aC \mid Dc\\
&A \to Bb\\
&B \to Sb\\
&C \to Sa\\
&D \to \epsilon \\
\end{align}